# Listening to UITouch event along with UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating a custom UIView and adding a UITapGestureRecognizer on it. I have a handler for the tap gesture. But at the same time I want my UIView to listen to touchesBegan & touchesEnded methods. I have implemented gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: method also but touchesBegan/touchesEnded methods does not get called. Any clue why?

**Inside my custom UIView**

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)iGestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)iTouch {
    return YES;
}
```

**Inside my view controller**

```
MyCustomView aCustomView = [[[MyCustomView alloc] init] autorelease];
                UIGestureRecognizer *myGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
[aCustomView addGestureRecognizer:myGestureRecognizer];
                [myGestureRecognizer release];
```

Comment: I always thought touchesBegan only applied to the master viewController's view.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set `cancelsTouchesInView` (and likely `delaysTouchesBegan` and `delaysTouchesEnded`) to `NO` for the gesture recognizer. The default behavior of a gesture recognizer is to avoid having both it and the view process the touch. These settings let you fine-tune that behavior.

Comment: I sure wish I was getting that behaviour you mention. I am using the default settings, yet my touches methods still get called. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869944/how-to-prioritize-gesture-recognizers-and-touches-in-a-uiview

Comment: @RobNapier would failing to put cancelsTouchesInView be linked to my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170876/random-crash-on-pickerview-didselect-cfrunloop-is-calling-out-to-a-source1-p?noredirect=1#comment79305779_46170876

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier, you need to set the `cancelTouchesInView` property to `NO` on your `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

From the Apple Docs:

> cancelsTouchesInView—If a gesture recognizer recognizes its gesture,
>   it unbinds the remaining touches of that gesture from their view (so
>   the window won’t deliver them). The window cancels the previously
>   delivered touches with a (touchesCancelled:withEvent:) message. If a
>   gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture, the view receives
>   all touches in the multi-touch sequence.

Further reading:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/