# How to prioritize gesture recognizers and touches in a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

From reading the [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it is implied that the API will handle the prioritizing of touches and gesture controls for you, making sure that your `touchesBegan` and related methods are not called on the view unless the gesture recognizers have first failed:

> A window delivers touch events to a gesture recognizer before it delivers them to the hit-tested view attached to the gesture recognizer. Generally, if a gesture recognizer analyzes the stream of touches in a multi-touch sequence and does not recognize its gesture, the view receives the full complement of touches. **If a gesture recognizer recognizes its gesture, the remaining touches for the view are cancelled.**

I have added a swipe gesture to my view, and it is working. Via some logging, when I do a single swipe, the method reports as such. However, my `touchesBegan` method is *also* reporting via its log, despite that the `touchesCancelled` method is, as expected, also receiving a message.

I want, and expect, the gesture recognize to prevent `touchesBegan` or `touchesMoved` from being called.

So my question is: for the gesture recognizer to in fact delay touches based on its state, is there additional setup necessary? The docs do not suggest anything else as necessary.

My setup is simply:

```
 swipeUpTwoFinger=[[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleSwipeUp:)]autorelease];
swipeUpTwoFinger.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
swipeUpTwoFinger.numberOfTouchesRequired=2;
[self addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpTwoFinger];
```

I have also tried this test to make sure a recognizer has failed before processing with `touchesBegan` (this test should *not* be necessary if you believe what the docs say above) but the `touchesBegan` is still processing the log line after this test:

`if (swipeUpTwoFinger.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need:
`swipeUpTwoFinger.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;`

Comment: indeed I just discovered that it is not enabled by default. Thanks.